# Properties that are not preserved under homeomorphism

Tags: general-topology

Homeomorphism establishes a very strong relationship between topological spaces. We know that many important properties such as compactness and connectedness are preserved under homeomorphism, and fundamental groups of such spaces are isomorphic.

I wish to gain some more intuition on the possible limits of homeomorphism, so I was wondering if you have any examples of properties that are not preserved under homeomorphism?

Searching SE I found one such example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/134400/preservation-of-completeness-under-homeomorphism), which discusses completeness. I think that Vadim's answer was particularly good, since it shows that while the choice of metric is independent of the existence of homeomorphism, the fact that a space $X$ is homeomorphic to a complete metric space means it is metrizable by some complete metric.

So are there any more properties like the above? Or ones that entirely break under homeomorphism?

Comment: All topological properties are preserved under homeomorphisms. (In other words, completeness is a metric property, not a topological property)

Comment: Names are not preserved by homeomorphisms, e.g., there may be a homeomorphism of the plane with itself which takes the point named $(1,2)$ to the point named $(3,4)$.

Answer (score 8):

What about a sequence being a Cauchy sequence? The spaces $\mathbb R$ and $(0,+\infty)$ are homeomorphic (with respect to the usual metric). A homeomorphism between them is $\exp\colon\mathbb{R}\longrightarrow(0,+\infty)$, whose inverse is $\log$. The sequence $(1/n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is a Cauchy sequence in $(0,+\infty)$, but $\bigl(\log(1/n)\bigr)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is not.

Comment: Good one. A homeomorphism between metric spaces preserves convergent sequences but not necessarily all Cauchy sequences.

Answer (score 3):

A general homeomorphism does not preserve distances. If we have two metric spaces $X, Y$ and a homeomorphism $f:X\to Y$, $f$ need not be an isometry. For instance, we can take $f:[0,1]\to [0,2]$ given by $f(x)=2x$. This map is not distance preserving, because 
$$d(1,0)\ne d(f(1),f(0))=d(2,0).$$
The upshot is that properties that rely on a stronger structure than the topology on the space need not be preserved under isomorphism. For instance, the metric structure need not be preserved.

Comment: Similarly, there are homeomorphism $\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ that do not respect the additive abelian group structure ...

Answer (score 2):

You could look at properties describing the differential topology of a differential (as opposed to merely topological) manifold. Surely some properties preserved by diffeomorphisms are not in general preserved by homeomorphisms.

Cf. this question [Properties preserved by diffeomorphisms but not by homeomorphisms](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/85860/346324)

Answer (score 2):

(I).  A non-compact metrizable space $X$ has an unbounded metric $d,$ and the metric $e(x,y)=\min (1,d(x,y))$ generates the same topology, so 
 $id_X$ is a homeomrphism from $(X,e)$ to $(X,d).$ So being a bounded subset of $X$ is not a topological property: $X$ itself is bounded with respect to $e$ but not with respect to $d.$

(II).  For a metric space $(X,d)$ and $Y\subset X$ and $r>0$ let  $Y$ be $r$-dense in $X$ iff $\forall x\in X \;\exists y\in Y\;(d(x,y)<r).$ Equivalently $Y$ is $r$-dense  in $X$ iff $\cup_{y \in Y}B_d(y,r)=X.$

The function $f(x)=\tan x$ is a homeomorphism from $(-\pi /2,\pi /2)$ to $\mathbb R$ (with the usual metric on both spaces). Any non-empty subset of $(-\pi /2,\pi /2)$ is $\pi$-dense in $(-\pi /2,\pi /2)$ but $\{2^n:n\in \mathbb N\}$ is not $r$-dense in $\mathbb R$ for any $r>0.$

(III).(Digression). When $X$ is compact and metrizable there are some important properties  shared by all metrics for $X$: Any metric for $X$ is bounded,complete, totally bounded, and satisfies the Lebesgue covering theorem.

A non-compact metrizable space has an incomplete metric. This is not an easy result.

Comment: In (II),  I could also have said that $\{0\}$ is not $r$-dense in $\Bbb R$ for any $r>0.$

Answer (score 2):

You may be also interested in other kind of mappings (continuous, quotient, open, closed, opened and closed, perfect, ...) and operations (taking a subspace, or the finite, countable, infinite cartesian product or sum) that preserve topological and topologically-related properties (being $T_0$, $T_1$, ..., locally, sequentially, countably, weakly, strongly (para-) compactness, being lindelof, metrizable, ...).

In such a case you should consult Engelking's General Topology that gathers and presents these questions in outline form at the end of the book.

Answer (score 2):

You may study $Isometry$  which is stronger than $homomorphism$,It is a bijective map $f:(X,d_1) \longrightarrow (X,d_2)$ defined as $d_1(a,b)=d_2(f(a),f(b))$;As it preserves the distance between these two spaces it will help you.

Answer (score 2):

We have the completeness as well which is not preserve 
$\Bbb R$ is homeomorphic to $(-1,1)$ which is not complete but $\Bbb R $ is complete. [A bijection is given by](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2606116/injectivity-of-a-function-fracx1x/2606131#2606131)

$$\phi(x) = \frac{x}{1+|x|} \in (-1,1),~~~~\forall x\in \Bbb R.$$

Answer (score 2):

Two subspaces of a topological space can be homeomorphic while the first is a closed set of the topological space and the other is not.

For example, in $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the usual product topology, $\mathbb{R}$$\times$$0$ $\simeq$ $\mathbb{R}$ $\simeq$ $\mathbb{(0,1)}$ $\simeq$ $\mathbb{(0,1)}$$\times$$0$, where $\simeq$ means homeomorhpism. $\mathbb{R}$$\times$$0$ is closed in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\mathbb{(0,1)}$$\times$$0$ is not closed.

Thus, it is possible that two homeomorhpic spaces can be embedded in a topological space, where the first is a closed set there and the other is not.