# Injectivity of a function $\frac{x}{1+|x|}$

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, analysis, functions

> Let $f: \mathbb R \to  (-1,1)$
>
> $x \in $ $\mathbb R$,  $f(x) = \frac{x}{1+|x|} $
>
> Show that f is (1-1)

What I did : $x,y \in $ $\mathbb R$

$f(x)=f(y)$ iff $$\frac{x}{1+|x|} =\frac{y}{1+|y|}\Rightarrow\left| \frac{x}{1+|x|} \right| =\left| \frac{y}{1+|y|} \right| \\\Rightarrow \frac{|x|}{1+|x|} =\frac{|y|}{1+|y|}\Rightarrow |x|=|y|$$ $\Rightarrow$  $x=y$ or $x=-y$

If $x=-y,\frac{y}{1+|y|} =\frac{-y}{1+|y|}\Rightarrow y=-y$

It is only valid for unique real value of $y$ that is $0$ namely $f(x) \neq f(y)$ for other values of $y$. Thus $x=y$

I think it is not sufficient for injectivity, can someone correct me please?

Comment: No, your answer seems perfectly fine.

Comment: You have almost completed the proof: $f(x)=f(y)\Longrightarrow x=-y, \text{or}\  x=y\Longrightarrow x=-y=0,\ \text{or}\ x=y\Longrightarrow x=y.$

Comment: Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You obtained that $|x|=|y|$ then replacing this in   the first equality you get

$$\frac{x}{1+|x|} =\frac{y}{1+|y|} \Longleftrightarrow\frac{x}{1+|x|} =\frac{y}{1+|x|}\Longleftrightarrow x=y$$

Comment: It is better then mine thanks..

Comment: okay thanks again

Comment: I upvoted. I have earned downvote as a new privilege  :)

Comment: @esrabasar ok cool happy for you

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is fine, maybe you just have to write it a bit differently at the end : 
$$x=y \quad \text{or}  \quad x=-y$$
If $x=-y$, then, as you shown, $y=-y$ which implies $y=0$, which implies on its turn $x=-y=0=y$. If $y\neq 0$, $x=y$.

So, in ALL CASES, you have $x=y$. The injectivity is well-proven.

Comment: The question only asks for injectivity!

Comment: Yes, for the question of esarabasar, but within the question : "Show that f is (1-1)" (one-to-one? so that we have bijectivity too?)

Comment: @Netchaiev A one-to-one function $f$ is by definition injective. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-to-one

Comment: @user236182 : ok! So one-to-one function = injective ; one-to-one correspondance = bijective function. I edited my answer .... (but here, the function of interest still bijective :p )